# asp.net C# Gridview nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Dear all genius please help me with this had been trying everywhere but no luck. I am trying to open my nested gridview for a single Parent Row but gets open the entire parent row with one single record of the child row. It should be when I click the  button of the Parent gridview row then the record for the particular row should display in the Child gridview in the same Parent row, but in my case the record of the Parent row shows up and the Child gridview gets open in all the parent row. Please need in help :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPEHX.jpg)

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView4" AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UId" class="" CellPadding="4" PageSize="5">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Type" Visible="false">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFileType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileType") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image Name" Visible="false">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblImageName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Image2" class="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("pic") %>' OnCommand="blah_Command" CommandName='<%# Eval("UId") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("pic") %>' />

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="position: relative" Visible="false">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FileSize" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ShareByUserId" HeaderText="Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void blah_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row2 in GridView4.Rows)
    {
        row2.FindControl("pnlOrders").Visible = true;

        string customerId = e.CommandName.ToString();
        GridView gvOrders = row2.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
        BindOrders(customerId, gvOrders);
    }
}

private void BindOrders(string customerId, GridView gvOrders)
{
    gvOrders.ToolTip = customerId;
    gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select * from SShare where UId='{0}'", customerId));
    gvOrders.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Code is mostly correct. Please use parameters in query. 
First of all why are you writing: `foreach (GridViewRow row2 in GridView4.Rows)`? Use sender and relative container instead of that code.

If it won't fix, can you try to do it all in RowDataBound event without ImageButton? I'd suggest to change your way to think: GridvView is difficult to use in this way. You can use an overlay (thickbox, colorbox...) and open the nested GridView in that. Or you perform your goal client side...

Comment: @Emanuele Thanks, let me check and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping all the rows in `GridView4`, so every nested GridView will be filled with data.
What you need is the row number of the row that the clicked LinkButton is in, and use that to find the nested GridView.

```
protected void blah_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //get the current datagrid item from the sender
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);

    //the row index of the gridviewrow
    int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;

    //find the correct nested grid using the row index
    GridView gvOrders = GridView4.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
}
```

Comment: protected void blah_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
     {
  ImageButton imgshow = (sender as ImageButton);
         GridViewRow row = (imgshow.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
         row.FindControl("pnlOrders").Visible = true;
         GridView gvOrders = GridView4.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
         string customerId = e.CommandName.ToString();
         BindOrders(customerId, gvOrders);
 }